# Current request is not of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper] in spring test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test

I have following method in my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/owner/terminals/edit",
            "/admin/terminals/edit" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editTerminal(@RequestParam(value = "terminalId") Long terminalId,
            @ModelAttribute TerminalRawDTO terminalDto,
            Principal principal, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs, SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper securityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper)
            throws IOException {
             ...
```

I have wrote following test for this method:

```
Terminal terminal = Mockito.mock(Terminal.class);
        Mockito.when(terminal.getTerminalId()).thenReturn(1L);
        Mockito.when(terminalService.findTerminalById(anyLong())).thenReturn(terminal);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/owner/terminals/edit").principal(principal).secure(true)
                .param("name", "")
                .param("terminalId", "1")
                .param("description", "")
                .param("startWorkTime", "")
                .param("endWorkTime", "")
                .param("mapLat", "0.0")
                .param("mapLng", "0.0")
                .param("terminalGroup", "1")
                .param("cost", "0.0")
                .param("operationSystem", "")
                .param("address", "")
                .param("moderationComment", "1"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
                .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/owner/terminals?panel=edit_error1"));
```

I see error:

```
testEditTerminal(com.terminal.controller.owner.OwnerTerminalsControllerTest): Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper]: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest@628c4ac0
```

How to fix it?

### P.S.

If to remove `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper securityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` from argument controller - all works fine

### P.S.

I added following code to my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/securityContext.xml")
public class OwnerTerminalsControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter;
         ....
 }
```

securityContext.xml:

```
<beans:beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" pattern="/admin/**" authentication-manager-ref="adminAuthenticationManager">
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/loginAdmin" login-processing-url="/admin/j_spring_security_check_admin"
                    default-target-url="/admin"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginAdminFailed"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="authAdminSuccessHandler"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/j_spring_security_check_admin" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/accounts/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/users/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/money/**" access="ROLE_FINANSIER, ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/moderation/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN,ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/moderation/pictures"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN,ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/statistic/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/rules/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/addImageToTerminal"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/terminals/deleteTerminalImage"
                       access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/systemGroupsModeration" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/adminUsers" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/contentModeration/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/campaignModeration/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/monitoring" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/loginAdmin"/>
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="${http.port}" https="${https.port}"/>
        </port-mappings>
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/" />
    </http>
    <http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager">
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER"/>
        <form-login login-page="/"
                    default-target-url="/member/personalAccount"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"/>

        <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/common/*" filters="none" /> -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/createCompany/addParams" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/owner/*" access="ROLE_OWNER"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/getImage/*"
                       access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_OWNER,ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUPERADMIN, ROLE_TERMINAL_MODERATOR, ROLE_IMAGE_MODERATOR, ROLE_CAMPAIGN_MODERATOR, ROLE_FINANSIER, ROLE_MODERATOR"/>

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
        <port-mappings>
            <port-mapping http="${http.port}" https="${https.port}"/>
        </port-mappings>
        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="userSecurityService" class="com.terminal.service.impl.UserSecurityService"/>
    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler" class="com.terminal.filter.RoleAuthSuccessHandler"/>

    <beans:bean id="authAdminSuccessHandler" class="com.terminal.filter.admin.RoleAuthAdminHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="adminSecurityService" class="com.terminal.service.admin.impl.TerminalAdminSecurityServiceImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="webexpressionHandler"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler"/>

    <authentication-manager id="adminAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="adminSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager id="internalUserAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userSecurityService">
            <password-encoder ref="noopEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="10"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="noopEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder"/>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>

    <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
                    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
                    <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Did you setup the mocking framework to use Spring Security?

Comment: @zeroflagL Yes. my code worked before I added SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper as argument into controller method

Comment: Due to problems like this and the setup tweaks they require I avoid MockMvc wherever possible and use rest-assured instead

Comment: Can you clarify what does it mean **rest-assured** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem, is that to be able to use a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` in the controller, the request must have been processed by a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` that will wrap the original request (here a `MockHttpServletRequest`) into a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`. According to [Spring Security reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-custom-filters), this filter is internal to Spring Security and is setup and run by the `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Your problem here is that the `springSecurityFilterChain` has not been called.

I could not test it, but according to Spring Framework documentation, you can register filter instances with a `MockMvc`:

*When setting up a MockMvc, you can register one or more Filter instances:*

```
mockMvc = standaloneSetup(new PersonController()).addFilters(
              new CharacterEncodingFilter()).build();
```

*Registered filters will be invoked through MockFilterChain from spring-test and the last filter will delegates to the DispatcherServlet.*

You must manually build and configure the `MockMvc` in order to mimic the filter declaration in a classic `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In your use case, I would use something like:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    DelegatingFilterProxy filterProxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy(
            "springSecurityFilterChain", wac);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
        addFilter(filterProxy, "/*").build();
}
```

This should work provided the securityContext.xml is used to build the `wac` application context.

---

But **BEWARE**. Even if it works, it adds complexity to the nice Spring test framework even for simple URL mapping tests. Because you are tying Spring security in a controller method, when the whole Spring machinery tends to favor *separation of concerns*. So you should ask yourself whether using `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` in a controller method is really necessary. Best pratices suggest that security should lie in `intercept-url` elements form simple url rules, of in method security at service level for more complex use cases. If you need to track current user, use a filter or an interceptor to put relevant information in a request of a session attribute and just use ordinary `ServletRequest` (of `WebRequest` or `HttpServletRequest`) in you controller if you need an element that Spring MSV does not extract for you: tests will be simpler, as will be future evolutions if you later change the security layer.

In you current use case, you are falling in another trap for your test:

- you declare a principal for the request
- spring security filter pass all its filters and wraps the request in a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`... but the SecurityContext has never been populated, so the principal in the wrapped request is null!

For the principal in initial request to populate the SecurityContextHolder, you will have to setup a `J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` in the security filter chain, and a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` in the authentication manager, but only for the test profile.

Alternatively, you could create from scratch a custom filter, that would:

- take the principal from a request
- if it is null, clear the SecurityContextHolder
- else

  - use it to build an Authentication object (I would advise a TestingAuthenticationToken) if it is not already one
  - build a SecurityContext and populates is with that Authentication object
  - populates the SecurityContextHolder with that SecurityContext
- wraps the original request in a SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper
- pass the wrapped request to the filter chain

and use it in configuring the MockMvc.

It is not that complex, but it adds another class dedicated to test, that should be itself tested. And anyway, the principal in the wrapped request will be the authentication object, because the wrapped request returns what is in security context for `getUserPrincipal()`. That's why I said before that tying Spring Security in a controller method was a bad idea.

If you want to try it, code for the custom filter could look like:

```
public class TestingWrapperFilter implements Filter {
    private Object credentials = "password";
    private String rolePrefix = "ROLE";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest sr, ServletResponse sr1, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) sr;
        Principal principal = req.getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            Authentication auth;
            auth = (principal instanceof Authentication) ? (Authentication) principal :
                    new TestingAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials);
            SecurityContext sc = new SecurityContextImpl();
            sc.setAuthentication(auth);
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(sc);
        }
        else {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
        sr = new SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper(req, rolePrefix);
        fc.doFilter(sr, sr1);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void setCredentials(Object credentials) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    public void setRolePrefix(String rolePrefix) {
        this.rolePrefix = rolePrefix;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I add   **@Autowired
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter;** - it resolves as null and as a result I see error:  **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: filter cannot be null**

Comment: **or build and configured by hand if not.**  - please clarify how

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I suppose that when you run the application (outside of test environment), you use a SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter . How is it declared and configured?

Comment: I added to topic my spring security configuration. also in web.xml I have following listener: **<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>**

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I digged further in SpringSecurity doc, and found that  `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` is normally setup and run by the Spring Security machinery and should not be used alone. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: I will return to your answer after configuring test. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756906/spring-context-doesnt-load-succesfully-in-tests

Comment: problem described in topic is disappear but now principal passes as null although in test it is not null

Comment: As you can see in my topic I have invocation like this: **mockMvc.perform(post("/owner/terminals/edit").principal(principal)**

Comment: I tried **this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).addFilter(filterProxy, "/*")
    .apply(springSecurity()).build();** - doesn't help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765411/why-controller-accepts-principal-as-null-from-integration-test

Comment: @gstackoverflow: That's the reason why I said it was dangerous to tie Spring Security in a controller. SpringMVC test allows you to put a principal in a request. But Spring security wraps the original request and only look at what it identified itself. See my updated answer.

Comment: **it was dangerous to tie Spring Security in a controller** - I didn't catch this phrase. Problem that I use together mock and integration tests?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: No the problem is to use `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper securityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` as a controller method parameter.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I slightly improved the custom filter to wrap the request even if original principal is null, and keep it unchanged if it is already an `Authentication`

Answer (score 0):

"/owner/terminals/*" or "/owner/**"  url should be specified in spring-security.xml to avoid that exception. if you perform test for the "/admin/terminals/edit" you will not get that kind of exception, i think. please try once..

```
<intercept-url pattern="/owner/**" access="ROLE_OWNER"/>
```

or

```
<intercept-url pattern="/owner/terminals/*" access="ROLE_OWNER"/>
```

i hope this works...