# Spring, Failed to load ApplicationContext in tests

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-test

I have following web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd
        ">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    ...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    ...

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/webContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thus from web.xml I load two configuration files:

`applicationContext.xml` and `webContext.xml`

I copied these files to `resources/META-INF`  and  write integration test with following signature:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml", "classpath:META-INF/webContext.xml"})
public class OwnerTerminalsControllerTest {
```

when I try to execute any method from test I see error like this:

```
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'conversionService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/webContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'terminalGroupFormatter' while setting bean property 'formatters' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'terminalGroupFormatter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.terminal.dao.TerminalGroupDao com.terminal.formatter.TerminalGroupFormatter.terminalGroupDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'terminalGroupDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.terminal.dao.impl.TerminalGroupDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 70 more
24.09.2015 12:28:49 ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7181ae3f] to prepare test instance [com.terminal.controller.owner.OwnerTerminalsControllerTest@6bc248ed]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
    .....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 70 more
```

For me two configurations looks same and I have not ideas why from test context cannon be loaded

### P.S.

inside `applicatioContext` I have following lines:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/dataContext.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/restTemplateContext.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/securityContext.xml"/>
```

dataContext:

```
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd

         http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.terminal.domain, com.terminal.dao, com.terminal.utils"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>mymessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <task:scheduler id="jobScheduler" pool-size="10"/>

    <beans profile="test">

        <bean id="wrappedDataSource" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetName" value="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL" />
            <property name="username" value="sa" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="wrappedDataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    </beans>
    <beans profile="dev">

        <bean id="wrappedDataSource" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetName" value="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="wrappedDataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc-local.properties"/>
        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
              p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </beans>
    <beans profile="prod">

        <bean id="wrappedDataSource" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetName" value="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="wrappedDataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
        <bean id="dataSource"
              class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
              p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
              p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

Comment: The cause of the error seems to be a non existent `SessionFactory` bean. How do you declare the database in applicationContext.xml?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta topic updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dataContext.xml, the SessionFactory bean is always declared under a profile, and your test configuration does not declare any of them, so the bean is never loaded in the application context causing the `No qualifying bean ...` error. You should declare an active profile:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml", "classpath:META-INF/webContext.xml"})
public class OwnerTerminalsControllerTest {
```

Comment: Yes this problem fixed)